# Grabbing the latest position (y coordinate) of a transitioning element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, sass, framer-motion

The following is a portion of a react component that gradually animates down to its required position on y-axis (from `-500` to `0`) when the app fires up.

Is there a way to grab the spans' latest y coordinate while they are transitioning. The purpose for the same is an interim onScroll animation that is supposed to fire up while the animation is underway.

```
const topContainer = {
    show: {
      transition: {
        delayChildren: 8,
      },
    },
  };

  const topItems = {
    show: {
      transition: {
        staggerChildren: 0.6,
        staggerDirection: -1,
      },
    },
  };

  const topLetters = {
    initial: {
      y: -500,
    },
    show: {
      y: 0,
      transition: {
        ease: [0, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0],
        duration: 30,
      },
    },
  };


  return (
    <section className={styles.heroSection}>
      <div className={styles.heroSection_content}>
        <motion.div
          variants={topContainer}
          initial="initial"
          animate="show"
          className={styles.topContainer}
        >
          <motion.h1 variants={topItems} className={styles.text_enabling}>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>E</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>n</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>a</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>b</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>l</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>i</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>n</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>g</motion.span>
          </motion.h1>
          <motion.h1 variants={topItems} initial="initial" animate="show">
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>E</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>n</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>t</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>e</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>r</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>p</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>r</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>i</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>s</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>i</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>n</motion.span>
            <motion.span variants={topLetters}>g</motion.span>
          </motion.h1>
        </motion.div>
       </div>
    </section>
```

I think useMotionValue hook by framer motion might help but I am not quite aware as to how it works and the docs do not shed much light on the topic.
Thanks!